# Writing transformation pass in Polly

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

How to write a Polly pass which can run on `SCoPs` detected by the Polly.

I found [this](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#quick-start-writing-hello-world) on llvm website but this shows to write LLVM Pass. Are writing polly pass and llvm pass are exactly the similar?

Answer (score 1):

Although I've played around with `Polly`, I haven't written a pass with/for it.
However, it should be fairly straightforward, since the main principles are the same since [`runOnScop`](https://polly.llvm.org/doxygen/classpolly_1_1ScopPass.html) is based on a `RegionPass`.

Poking around in the Polly codebase you can find examples like [this](https://github.com/nobled/polly/blob/master/lib/Interchange.cpp).
Building will depend if you add your pass in Polly or have it as standalone, in which case it will have to link against Polly's shared object.